# When are unit tests runnable from the Test Results panel in Pycharm?

Tags: pycharm

Sometimes after running `pytest` there is a nifty feature that we can re-run or even debug whichever [failed] test we want by right-clicking on that test.  But other times there is a message "Nothing here".

[image]

Unfortunately I've been seeing the latter recently.  I did not change pycharm versions and it is the same project.  Any ideas what scenarios allow us to use that useful "right click to run/debug" feature?